# why is "wanting" grammatically incorrect, in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> Not seeing any video games the kids **wanting** and acknowledging we certainly don't need any of them, I continued browsing in the toy department.

Why is *wanting* grammatically incorrect?

I cannot figure out the error.

Comment: It should be *wanted*: *Not seeing any video games the kids wanted, and acknowledging we certainly don't need any of them, I continued browsing in the toy department.*

Comment: Did you write this sentence? It doesn't make sense. "Not seeing any [of the] video games **[that] the kids wanted**..." The phrase in bold describes the games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the continuous form of a verb - the *-ing* form - you need a 'helping' verb to place the tense, and in your example there isn't one.

For example:

- He **is** wanting a new bike.
- He **was** wanting to go this morning but couldn't.
- He **will be** wanting more.

Your example could work with '*are*':

> Not seeing any video games the kids *are wanting*....

However, it doesn't sound very natural. We would probably say "*want*" or perhaps "*wanted*", but 'want' matches 'need' which is used later, so I'd go with that.